# Issuing a post request iPhone->Server from xcode

Tags: iphone, post

I've done many searches but none of the code fragments I find seem to work for me.  I have the following fragment in xcode for running within my iPhone app:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blah.blah.com/rec.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSData *body = [@"data=crap" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *bodyLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
[request setValue:bodyLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];    
[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:NULL];
```

The rec.php is called fine but the post data does not make it through.  The entry $_POST['data'] is empty.  Could anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is not directly related to your question. But i noticed you are using synchronous request. This will block the UI if the data parsing takes time to load. What would be a recommended approach is to use asynchronous request. This [post here](http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2011/04/nsurlconnection-synchronous-asynchronous/) explains it nicely.

Comment: Sorry, I put the xcode tag on because the code is written in xcode.  This is being issued from my iPhone app.

Comment: Can you test our server with a roughly equivalent CURL to make sure the mistake isn't there?

Comment: When working with situations that require a web service. A approach that I recommend is to make sure the web service does what it is intended to do. That is, it works. You can try what @danh said with CURL, or if you are a GUI person, then you can use a REST client (assuming you are using REST, if not, you should). The [REST client on Mac by WizTools](http://blog.wiztools.org/2009/10/mac-os-x-edition-of-restclient.html) is a good tool. With the web service problem solved, you can be rest assured it works, and you can then concentrate on fixing your code on the client application.

Comment: Yeah, I hereby apologize for wasting everyone's time as I found the error was in my php.  I've done enough php that it didn't even occur to me.  Thanks to everyone!